# partial specialization on dependant name

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm building a template type system for arithmetic operations and I need to add some partial specializations for automatic simplification.

For example, I have a struct `min`:

```
struct unknown_t {};

template<typename f>
struct min {
    using type = unknown_t;
};
```

which represents `-f` (unknown until `f` is known).

I need to express that `-(-f) = f`. I tried this :

```
template<typename f>
struct min<typename min<f>::type> {
   using type = f;
};
```

which fails with

`class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced;`

I tried to add some type_traits, additional dummy template parameters, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work like this. Consider that `min<f>::type` is `unknown_t` for any `f` (unless you specialize it). Hence you cannot deduce `f` from `min<f>::type`

Consider to change the design slightly and specialize for `min<f>` rather than `min<f>::type`:

```
template<typename f>
struct min<min<f>> {
   using type = f;
};
```